# How Can I Edit the Font Size of Elapsed Time on Display?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I watch a bunch of stuff on VLC Media Player on my TV. Elapsed-Time and Time-Remaining numbers are way too small for me to see well. Is there a way to increase the size or create a separate elapsed time clock that is scalable in size? Thank you.

Comment: You can try another skin, or create your own. See here: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php Quick google search turned up this skin made for QHD screens: https://beowulf0.deviantart.com/art/QHD-skin-672766796

Answer (score 0):

VLC allows you to use custom skins. See here for more info and some skins:
https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.html

A quick Google search turned up this skin which is designed for QHD screens, which means it has large buttons and font size.
https://beowulf0.deviantart.com/art/QHD-skin-672766796

[image]

If you can't find a skin that works for you, you can always create your own:
https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skineditor.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the skin ftouch100.vlt. Link to download here http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-skins2-go.php?url=ftouch100.vlt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1191380)